# Findpeaks expected X to be increasing valued

Tags: matlab, debugging

I'm starting out with matlab to analyse some data. I want to find the peaks in a gyroscope signal, but for some reason I'm getting an error saying "Expected X to be increasing valued".

The full code for this is the following:

```
load logfile_6_2

figure;
axes;
hold on;

rate = inertia.node_137.data(inertia.node_137.data(:,1)>1161 & inertia.node_137.data(:,1)<1221, :);
gyro = rate(:,inertia.node_137.fields.gyro);
taxis = rate(:,inertia.node_137.fields.time);

plot(taxis, gyro(:,1), 'r')
findpeaks(gyro(:,1), taxis, 'MinPeakDistance', 2);
```

The gyro variable contains 3 directions, and I want the x in this case, which is why i use gyro(:,1).
The X that the error seems to be speaking of is the taxis, which is simply the timestamps of the data. This is increasing, so I do not understand why I get this error. Does anyone have an idea how this could happen? Thanks in advance!

Edit:
This is an example of the taxis data

```
830.5100
830.5110
830.5120
830.5130
830.5140
830.5150
830.5160
830.5170
830.5180
830.5190
830.5200
```

Comment: Have you tried without the 'taxis' ?

Comment: I have tried with only "findpeaks(gyro(:,1));", that works without problems

Comment: Can you share few values from 'taxis'? Perhaps you can add them in the post. Seems like this is creating the problem.

Comment: What is the output of `all(diff(taxis)>0)`?

Comment: The output of that is
`ans = logical 0`

Comment: then not all of your values are increasing. maybe there are duplicate values, or trailing zeros or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the insights. The problem turned out to be a bug in the way the taxis was constructed. It has been fixed!